# fultter Firebase Realtimebase question. Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter

my json file is like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6djL9.png)

I want to use it in flutter. json file loaded from firebase.
my code is like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFYKe.png)

and I made model.dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1w0Df.png)

This error message appears on the console.

Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

How should I create the code?
Help.
I am a beginner T_T
thank U.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. It is etiquette here to post the code and error messages as correctly formatted text and not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you, that some function expected a String, but received a HashMap instead.

In this case, `jsonDecode` is the cause.
From [the documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonDecode.html) you can see that it requires a String as a first argument.

But `event.snapshot.value` seems to be a HashMap already instead of a string. So you don't need to call `jsonDecode` on it. Take [this documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/usage/) as an example

Answer (score -1):

comment the print methods that locate in the function and retry